# VHDL 2008 Conditional code in ISE

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to synthesize a VHDL module which has a sintax like the following:

```
...
adc_0_ram_addr <= address_i when selector="000" else ( others => '0' );
...
```

However, when synthesizing while using ISE I got the following error:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1690 This construct is only supported in VHDL 1076-2008
```

My project is set to VHDL20XX instead of '93, so it should be ok refering to this poing.
I have googled it and I have found nothing.
How can I correctly set my ISE environment?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the complete code that's leading to your error! with the correct context, the line you posted works with ISE in 200X and '93 without any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: the language changes were not accomplished due to and write permission issue.

Comment: Could you explain - how did you fix the language changes?

Comment: @davidhood2 I simply verified the folder/files permissions, and set them accordingly to my needs (w+r+x).